# How to find the points of discontinuities in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Find the points of discontinuities in $\mathbb{R}$ of the function $f(x)=[\sin{x}]$

Note: $[x]$ is the greatest integer function

My approach

After a small calculation I can express $f(x)=[\sin{x}]$ in the following form:

> $$
>   f(x)=\begin{cases}
>                1, ~~ \text{if} ~~x =(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{2} \\
>                0, ~~\text{if} ~~x \in \bigcup_{n \ge 0}[2n\pi, (2n+1)\pi]\setminus\{(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\}\\\
>                -1,~~\text{otherwise}
>             \end{cases}
> $$
>   $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Please check whether this is right or wrong, specially please check $f(x)=0$ case.

Then I can say that $f$ has discontinuities at $\left(4n+1\right)\frac{\pi}{2}$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Unable to find the other discontinuities. Please help me in a bit details. 
Edit

Please solve this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could make it explicit what the square brackets stand for? One might reverse engineer your notation from the answer, of course.

Comment: @mic $[x]$ is the greatest integer function

Comment: From what I can tell you're correct.

Comment: Suggestion: Carefully work through what happens on the intervals $[-\pi, \pi]$ and (for good measure) $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$. Then use periodicity. (Your formula for $f$ looks good, aside from the union over $n \geq 0$ followed by "$n \in \mathbf{Z}$".)

Comment: @Justin I have edited. Would you now understand what I actually need?

Comment: @rama_ran, As far as I can tell you've classified the discontinuities fine. Your discontinuities occur at the maximum value of $\sin(x),$ that is when $\sin(x)=1,$ since these correspond to the maximums of $\sin,$ so when $\sin$ is positive, less than 1, you get $0,$ and when it is negative, you get $-1,$ so the way you've presented things looks just right. I agree with Andrew, in that you should ditch the union and just define your function for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}.$ Otherwise, this seems like the exact breakdown you need.

Comment: Maybe I'm just overlooking it, but it seems you haven't listed the zeros of $\sin$ as points of discontinuity of $f$.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. The discontinuities are exactly at the places where $sin(x)= 0$ or $sin(x)=1$ i.e. $n\pi$ and $2n\pi + \pi/2$. This is because when $sin(x) =0$, in a neighborhood of $x$ it will take both positive and negative values.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang please write in answer style in full

Comment: Graphing $y = \sin x$ and then $y = [\sin x]$ over $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$ seem simple enough. Can you explain where you're stuck? (I'm happy to help you reason through the question yourself, but because this appears to be homework I'm not going to write a solution. Where I teach, turning in someone else's work for credit without attribution normally results in expulsion for the second offense.)

Comment: It sounds like you know where the discontinuities are supposed to be, but your solution does not match the answer key. Is this the case? Also, what are [-1/2] and [+1/2]? There are different conventions out there, so this is crucial to know. With more context and a description of what makes you unsure (or stuck) would help a lot.

Comment: to see what @JoonasIlmavirta suggest, see one definition of integer part at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerPart.html and another definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions (identified with floor function). See also fractional part at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part . The answer to your question will be different depending on which definition you use. Do you know which definition you use? More specifically, is $[-1/2]=-1$ or $[-1/2]=0$ ?

Answer (score 0):

In the function $\lfloor sin(x)\rfloor$. We only need to check whether $sin(x)$ takes values 0 and 1. It is because $sin(x)$ takes values between $-1$ and $1$ and what the function $\lfloor\rfloor$ do is drop values in the interval $[0,1)$ to $0$ and in the interval $[-1,0)$ to $-1$ and if is $1$ give the value $1$.
$sin(n\pi)=0$ and $sin(2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})=1$.
So discontinuity appears at $n\pi$ and $2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all integer $n$.